# A simple two column layout with Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout

How to get a sidebar JPanel of a fixed with with Swing. Now I'm trying this:

```
public SidebarPanel() {
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));   
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, this.getPreferredSize().height));
    ...
```

But when I resize the window also the width of the sidebar changes. How to fix this?

Comment: Where do you put this panel? In what kind of layout?

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee in Swing that the preferred size is respected. This depends on the layout manager of the container.

If the container uses a BorderLayout, you can add the SidebarPanel using:

```
container.add(sidebarPanel, BorderLayout.EAST)
```

This will respect the preferred width.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to rely upon the good old [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). A good helper class is the [GBC](http://www.horstmann.com/articles/GBC.java), which will allow you to position elements with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BorderLayout, adding to JPanel

```
    mainContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainContent.add(pnlHeader, BorderLayout.WEST);
    mainContent.add(pnlResultList, BorderLayout.EAST);
```